# Can we get our personal voting data displayed on the Questions lists?

Tags: feature-request, voting

> **Exact Duplicate** (Meta Stack Overflow):
>   [Can we get our personal voting data displayed on the Questions lists?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72373/can-we-get-our-personal-voting-data-displayed-on-the-questions-lists)

There's been several times where I have been surfing the site, and noticed a question that I am not sure I've checked.  Even if I've checked the question before, I can't recall off-hand whether or not I've voted on it or its answer.

Is there a way we can have our personal voting history reflected to some degree or another, in the Questions listing?  For example, could there be an indicator as to whether or not we have already voted (up or down) on a question, and perhaps maybe an additional indicator as to whether we've up-voted any of its answers?

It would be very convenient to have some of this data available up-front, without actually having to view the question again.

Comment: This isn't specific to RPG.  You might get a better response at meta.stackoverflow.com

Comment: @PatLudwig - Done.  Thanks.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/72373/152399