# Can a question be closed as Exact Duplicate, when the duplicate is on another SE site?

Tags: feature-request, closing-questions, duplicates

Reference [this question](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/798/can-we-get-our-personal-voting-data-displayed-on-the-questions-lists).

I re-posted the same question on [MSO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/72373/152399), and it has since received little activity and no answers here.  Still, I'd like the question to stay on this site as a pointer to the other.  Can it be closed as an Exact Duplicate, with a referrer to MSO?

Answer (score 2):

No.  I tried to close as duplicate and put that URL in and it doesn't take it.

Comment: Thanks.  Changed the support tag to feature-request.  I know it's kinda out there, but maybe they'll put it through.

Comment: @Iszi: I edited in the duplicate link and voted to close it (as TL). Basically a manual dupe link. Anyone know if the 'Close as duplicate' process does more than close it and add the link?